# VB.NET Loop through DataGridView rows and update a value in the row based on 2 conditions

Tags: vb.net

what im trying to do is loop through the rows and update the sales rate based on 2 conditions. 1 condition is a value from a column in the same row and the 2nd condition is from a text label. But the result im getting is that changes don't take effect or get updated until a new row is added in the datagridview. here is my code so far any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
Try
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If txtTaxType.Text = "Inclusive" Then
            con = New SqlConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            Dim ct As String = "select PRate,PQty,BottleDeposit from product where PID=@d1 and POffer='Yes'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(ct)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", Val(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("PID").Value))
            cmd.Connection = con
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If rdr.Read() Then
                Dim BValue = rdr.GetValue(2)
                Dim PromoRate = rdr.GetValue(0)
                Dim PromoQty = Val(rdr.GetValue(1))
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    If Val(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Qty").Value) >= PromoQty Then
                        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("SalesRate").Value = PromoRate
                    End If
                    If lblpromo.Text >= 0.2 And Val(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("BD").Value) = BValue Then
                        row.Cells("SalesRate").Value = PromoRate
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

End Sub

I have tried to remove the Try/Catch to see any code errors but nothing showing in the debugger. so im guessing code is just missing something to help it fire the changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try to use CellEndEdit event instead

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
```